# Hibernate: how do I program an 'or' condition?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create an 'or' condition between two where conditions in the where clause, but the generated sql has ‘and’ instead of ‘or’.

**Code**

```
    if (pat.getFirstName() != null) 
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("firstName", pat.getFirstName()));
    if (pat.getLastName() != null) 
        criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like("lastName", pat.getLastName())));
```

**Generated where clause**

…… where this_.FIRST_NAME like ? and (this_.LAST_NAME like ?)

What am I missing here please?

Comment: The following change to the code worked.  It was a misunderstanding of hibernate API usage.  criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like("firstName", pat.getFirstName()), Restrictions.like("lastName", pat.getLastName())));

Comment: im glad you found the solution. could you please either answer your own question or delete it? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following change to the code worked. It was a misunderstanding of the hibernate API usage.

criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like("firstName", pat.getFirstName()), Restrictions.like("lastName", pat.getLastName())));